# RequiredFieldValidator Doesn't work with validationGroup

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's my Markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCrdtCrdNumber" ValidationGroup="val1" MaxLength="16" CssClass="txt" tyle="background: url(images/txtboxcredit.png) no-repeat right; padding-right: 192px;width: 182px;border:1px solid #ccc;" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ValidationGroup="val1" ID="reqtxtCrdtCrdNumber" ControlToValidate="txtCrdtCrdNumber" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Specify Card Number" runat="server">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

It just dont prevent my page from loading, even if i don't specify anything in the textbox.
What do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To venture a guess: you might be clicking a button to trigger a page reload, and this button does not have a validation group specified.

If there is a validation group defined, all relevant controls - buttons, inputs, validators - should indicate that they belong to the same validation group.

So:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ... ValidationGroup="val1" />
```

Comment: Yes! You are right. Very very thanks to remind me this

Comment: @AnilKumar, well, make sure to post your problems as similar questions, and someone will surely answer them. Could as well be me

Comment: if i do mention your answer as Answer then, would other  people be able to see my questions on comments?

Comment: @AnilKumar, other people won't look in comments for your other questions, to begin with. The best way to attract attention to your questions is to post them, well, as separate questions. To mark or not to mark is basically up to you - this is just an indicator for future visitors(who might google this up) that this answer helped you

Comment: This would not allow me to ask more questions now